# Which is more efficient, max or order by desc limit 1 in HIVE using spark version 2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hiveql, sqlperformance

As Hive keeps the data in distributed, Which query will be more efficient out of below two, when we have not consider that column in partition by or in bucketing.

1. `select max(stat_id) from stats_tbl ;`
2. `select stat_id from stats_tbl order by stat_id desc limit 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely `select max(stat_id) from stats_tbl` because `order by` requires gathering (read "lots of shuffle") all the data into a single reducer (and that's why you have to supply a `limit` clause with it) which will be inefficient compared to an aggregate function that can be computed *distributedly*.

Comment: It is hard to say what OP means by _HIVE using spark_, but speaking only about Spark SQL, difference should be negligible `order by stat_id desc limit 1` should use `TakeOrdered...` so the amount of data shuffled should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The order of query execution is like `from` -> `where` -> `group by` -> `having` ->`select` -> `order by` -> `limit`

So `select max(stat_id) from stats_tbl ;` is a simple scan operation which means it will iterate row by row only once but the query `select stat_id from stats_tbl order by stat_id desc limit 1;` will perform ordering after scanning after that it will apply `limit`.

And we also know that odering is costly operations then scanning so query `select max(stat_id) from stats_tbl;` is more efficient than `select stat_id from stats_tbl order by stat_id desc limit 1;`